# How to sanitize logs in Ubuntu?

Tags: log

How to filter system logs (like /var/log/syslog) so that they not contain sensitive data and can be safely used to analyze system problems (crashes etc.)?

Comment: One question at a time!! Since your 2nd question looks entirely different from the first, you should ask it as other question. So I suggest you to edit your question and make the modifications..

Comment: You'll probably have to clearly define what data you will consider sensitive.

Comment: @SauravKumar, in such cases, you can delete the other question(s) and leave a comment for the asker so they don't repeat the same mistake.

Comment: @vasa1: I'll remember your suggestion next time I see such post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you copy the sensitive log over to a temporary folder in your home. Then, from that folder, run something like this:

```
grep -Ev 'sensitive_term' sensitive.log > sanitized.log
```

Depending on the complexity of the clean-up, you may need to employ regex. `man grep` should get you started.